# Remote SSH login blocked without local Gnome login

Tags: ssh, centos6

I installed CentOS 6.7 from the full install media on a desktop machine at home. `sshd` has been reconfigured for private key authentication only.

When I go to log in via SSH from my laptop (OS X Yosemite, on the same local network) to the linux box, it will only work when I have actually logged in via Gnome locally. There is no authentication error, it just blocks and eventually times out. Once I log in locally via Gnome, I can log in remotely. As soon as I log out via Gnome locally, the remote SSH connection is blocked again (including open connections). If I log back in locally, connections are unblocked again. I have never had this problem when connecting to headless remote servers (AWS, other VPS providers).

Why is a remote login being blocked without the presence of a local login?

Here is all the relevant config (I hope).

`ls -al ~/.ssh`

```
drwx------.  2 chris chris 4096 Sep 16 09:25 .
drwx------. 35 chris chris 4096 Sep 16 11:28 ..
-rw-------.  1 chris chris  391 Sep 16 09:25 authorized_keys
-rw-------.  1 chris chris 3311 Sep 15 17:53 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--.  1 chris chris  737 Sep 15 17:53 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--.  1 chris chris  416 Sep 15 18:02 known_hosts
```

`chkconfig | grep ssh`

```
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

`iptables --list`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# Disable legacy (protocol version 1) support in the server for new
# installations. In future the default will change to require explicit
# activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of your [NetworkManager settings for the network interface](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Establishing_Connections.html#sec-Establishing_a_Wired_Ethernet_Connection).

You need to ensure that *both* of these settings are enabled:

- Connect automatically
- Available to all users

By default, for a *wireless* connection such as yours, "Available to all users" is disabled by default. This is enabled by default only for *wired* connections.

[image: NetworkManager interface settings]

When set, these settings cause the connection to be activated at boot time, rather than being associated with a user, in which case they are only activated when that user logs in at the console.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The problem lies in that the network connections were configured by NetworkManager, which Gnome doesn't start until a login has happened. It also tears them down when you log out. Uggh.

[No more NetworkManager](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/WpaSupplicant), no more problem.